# Does adding a second language and content affect first language ranking?

Tags: seo, multilingual

I'm about to add a second language to my website. The original website URL is `www.example.com/`. All new menus and content will appear in the URL under
`www.example.com/en/{second language}`.

Does adding the second language and content affect the first language ranking?
Are there any proactive actions I should take before doing this to let Search Engines know what's going on?

I want to make sure I'm not harming the original language ranking in anyway.

Comment: Your new URL does not look correct, is this a typo... `www.mywebsite.com/en/{second language}`? What language/content exists at `example.com/`?

Comment: i meant its www.mywebsite.com/en/       (for english language content)

Answer (score 1):

You should use www.example.com/{second language} as a folder for it (not en/{second language}). Also you can include a hreflangs between both language, showing Google they are the same pages, in different languages. However, even if you don't - your original rankings won't be affected. You are just adding second language, which is more content, which is good thing, not bad thing.